# Excel pivot chart change axis category from drop down

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I often use pivot chart to analyze data. It is a quick and easy. But I think it unpractical to have to drag fields in an out from the category filed when I investigate the data: A small example

```
car-model car-color crashes
ford      red       3
ford      black     4
toyota    red       2
toyota    red       3
```

First i make a pivot table with car-model and look at a plot which show the average crash for each car-model. But I want to look at the average crashes for the colors, I have to drag the car-model field out of the category box and drag car-color inside.

It is possible to make a drop-down menu I can choose the axix category from. 
In my real data I often have 10-20 different category fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion that includes a Pivot Chart, a few sub procedures and a Worksheet.Change event as per the comment from MacroMarc.

**1 - Set up Pivot Chart**

Starting from scratch with your sample data, select the range and use <kbd>Data | Insert Pivot Chart</kbd>. Confirm the selected range and specify that you'd like the PivotChart to be placed in cell K1. Actually, this is where the accompanying table ends up, and not the chart itself.

[image]

Initially, you can select both **car-model** and **car-color** under the PivotChart Fields. You'll need **crashes** too of course:

[image]

And speaking of crashes, you should proceed with clicking on <kbd>Sum of Crashes</kbd>:

[image]

And then click <kbd>Value Field Settings</kbd> and select **Average** under <kbd>Summarize value field by</kbd>:

[image]

Now you should end up with this:

[image]

**2 - Make a drop down menu**

First we'll ned a list where we can select the values we'd like to display.
Go to <kbd>Formulas | Name Manager</kbd>:

[image]

Click <kbd>New</kbd> and name your list `modelORcolor`. Make sure it refers to Range A1:B1 where your category names are located. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and then <kbd>Close</kbd> in the next window:

[image]

Now your new list is available for selection here if you'd like to double-check that the references are correct:

[image]

Next, select cell F2 and go to the <kbd>Data tab</kbd> and select <kbd>Data Validation</kbd>:

[image]

Under <kbd>Allow</kbd>, select <kbd>list</kbd>, and then enter your list name `=modelORcolor` in the Source Field (don't forget the EQUAL sign):

[image]

Now you can make your selection in the drop down list in cell F2:

[image]

**3 - Write some macros:**

Open the Visual Basic Editor and insert a new module.

[image]

There you can insert this little piece of code:

```
Sub setModel()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Average Crashes by Model"

    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("car-color").Orientation = xlHidden

    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("car-model")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub


Sub setColor()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Average Crashes by Color"
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("car-model").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("car-color")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Now you'll need to enable something that reacts to changes in your worksheet.
Go to Sheet1(Sheet1) in the Project Explorer:

[image]

And insert this little piece of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Range("E3").Value = "car-model" Then
        Call setModel
    End If

    If Range("E3").Value = "car-color" Then
        Call setColor
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The `Application.EnableEvents = False` is pretty important. Without it your code will trigger a chain reaction where changes in the snippets setModel and setColor trigger new reactions to changes in your worksheet.

Save your project (as an .xlsm file to allow macros to do their thing) and go back to your Excel Sheet.

Now you should be able to select **car-mode**l or **car-color** and see the desired results immediately in your Pivot Chart.

**car-model**

[image]

**car-color**

[image]

This solution is a bit limited to your sample data. A more flexible solution would include defining the data ranges and your list as dynamic ranges. But this solution should meet your specifiations. Give it a try and let me know if you run into any hurdles.